# How to fetch one document from Firebase and how to pass the id to delete it?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

this is my react native + firebase project and i have got 2 questions:

1. How do you suggest to pass the id from one CV ?
2. How do i fetch only one CV from firebase, cause if i try this it gives me this error:

   > TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'querySnapshot.docs.map')]

fetching all the documents from the collection is fine

```
getCv: () => {
  const id = "eccc137b-88be-470d-a0b8-c90b58a6473a"
  return firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('cvs')
      .doc(id)
      .get()
      .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        let cvs = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data())
        // console.log(doc.data())
        return cvs
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log('Error getting documents: ', error)
      })
}
```

This is my fetchCV method

```
  fetchCvs = async () => {
    try {
      const cvs = await this.props.firebase.getCv()
      //const cvs = await this.props.firebase.getCvs()
      //console.log(cvs)
      this.setState({ DATA: cvs, isRefreshing: false })
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
    }
  }
```

This is how i add one CV

```
onSubmit = async () => {
        try {
          const cv = {
            photo: this.state.image,
            title: this.state.title,
            description: this.state.description,
            salary: this.state.salary,
            createdAt: new Date().toISOString()
          }
          this.props.firebase.uploadCv(cv)

          this.setState({
            image: null,
            title: '',
            description: '',
            salary: '',
            createdAt: ''
          })
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e)
        }
      }
uploadCv: cv => {
        const id = uuid.v4()
        const uploadData = {
        id: id,
        cvPhoto: cv.photo,
        cvTitle: cv.title,
        cvDescription: cv.description,
        cvSalary: cv.salary,
        cvCreatedAt: cv.createdAt
        }
        return firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('cvs')
        .doc(id)
        .set(uploadData)
    },
```

and This is how i implemented the deleteCv method

```
onDelete = async () => {
        const cvId = {
          id: this.state.title
        }
        //this.props.firebase.deleteItem(cv);
        const deleteId = this.props.firebase.deleteItem(cv);
        console.log(deleteId)
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have different error, when I try similar code in nodejs, but I think its the same reason. In line:

`let cvs = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data())`

As you are using `get` on `DocumentReference` querySnapshot is instance of `DocumentSnapshot` which does not have property `docs`. I think you should use  `querySnapshot.data()` first and than manipulate on data returned.

Or maybe you wanted to use `get` on collection, not on document, and than you will get `QuerySnapshot` object and `.doc` array will be available.